# ASP.NET Core 8.0 MapRazorPages in a nonstartup assembly

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages, asp.net-core-8

I am writing an ASP.NET Core 8.0 website that I want to give people 2 different options. Either view the site in the cloud (hosted in shared IIS) or run a WPF desktop app that hosts the same server on the local wireless network.

In one assembly I have a .NET 8.0 minimal style razor pages website.  When I run the website from Visual Studio it works.

I have a WPF app that takes a project dependency on the website assembly. When I run the same website from the WPF app none of the Razor Pages appear in the route table, and I get 404 errors for everything. It seems to me that `app.MapRazorPages` is not searching any assemblies other than the startup assembly.

Is there an easy way to tell `MapRazorPages` to look in a different assembly?

I run the following code to start up the self-hosted webserver.

```
public static async Task RunWebsite(string[] args)
{
    var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
    builder.Host.UseServiceProviderFactory(
        new MelvilleServiceProviderFactory(true, i => new RegisterIocServices(i).Register()));
    builder.WebHost.UseUrls("http://*:7000");

    new ConfigAspNetServices(builder).Config();

    var app = builder.Build();

    await new HttpRequestPipeline(app).Configure(false);

    await app.RunAsync();
}
```

The code to configure the HTTP pipeline is shared between the website and local website

```cs
public readonly partial struct HttpRequestPipeline
{
    [FromConstructor] private readonly WebApplication app;

    public async ValueTask Configure(bool httpsOnly)
    {
        await using (var scope = app.Services.CreateAsyncScope())
        {
            await scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<InitalizationExecutor>().DoInitalize();
        }

        if (httpsOnly) RequireHttps();
        
        #if DEBUG
        app.UseRouteDebugger();
        #endif

        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.MapRazorPages();
    }

    private void RequireHttps()
    {
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        // Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseMigrationsEndPoint();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there an easy way to tell MapRazorPages to look in a different
> assembly?

Call `builder.Services.AddRazorPages().AddApplicationPart({targetassembly});`

You could check this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/advanced/app-parts?view=aspnetcore-8.0) for more details

Comment: Many thanks.  I knew it had to be something obvious, I just could not figure out what that obvious thing was.  I spent too much time investigating the Mapping command and forgot the add command,